# High pitched noise from engine unless brakes engaged

Tags: engine, toyota, noise

I'm driving a manual 96 Toytota T100, and recently the engine started making a high pitched, almost inaudible whine. Some things I've loosely figured out:

- It always stops when the brakes are applied, but doesn't stop for the clutch
- It seems independent of speed or revs
- It sounds cyclical with a slight random component, and fades in and out as I'm driving or stopped, but will usually go for 30 seconds at a time
- It seems independent of the heat/ac fan speed
- It seems temperature independent (both outdoors, and how long the truck has been running)

Any ideas where to start looking for the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From your question, the whine is linked into braking both when the veicle is stopped or moving. I would first look at the brake servo, its hoses and valves. A vacuum leak can give a whining like noise.

Comment: Also called the power brake booster, it has the master cylinder bolted to the front of it and mounts to the firewall.